# How to avoid invisible part of a RelativeLayout's child view from take touch event?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, touch-event

Let's say, there is a RelativeLayout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:eve="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.yyg.kaolamusic"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/A"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/B"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout >
```

then, how could we avoid the touch event go through to child A if we touch on B but B does not handle that touch event?

Comment: @NagarjunaReddy this is a simple question, since B overlay on A, user would not expected that A take some action (for example, scrolling) when they move finger over A, but RelativeLayout does act like that.

Comment: *how could we avoid the touch event go through to child A if we touch on B but B does not handle that touch event?* You make it handle that event by  returning true from the touch listener.

Comment: what are the childviews of each `LinearLayouts`?.. Though question aint that clear let me answer for what i understand is when you touch the childviews of `LinearLayout` B the ChildViews of `LinearLayout` A must not receive Touch and perform action is what my understanding.. if that is your problem try using setEnabled(false) for childviews.

Comment: @BobbeHoddi I don't want disable child B, they should be able to handle touch event when user move finger over it.

Comment: @Luksprog That is simple and it worked, I like that. You could answer this question with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a touch listener for the view B which consumes the touch event always, so A will never get the touch event.

Example code:

```
mA = (LinearLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.A);
    mA.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Touch A",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return false;
        }
    });
    mB = (LinearLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.B);
    mB.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Touch B",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: OK, I accept this answer. Did you see that comments above? I tended to let @Luksprog answer this...